# 2023 LED grow light voltage challenge?

Tags: led

What is the average circuit voltage for this lamp?

So, here's a brand new light that I'm examining to learn more. There's a picture and a diagram of the board layout. Uses nice wide 5mm traces all around.

I've been studying grow lights built with pretty straightforward hybrid circuits designed with a number of series-strings in parallel. But, in this new light, the load balancing looks even more complicated. While we can divide the board into three sections -- top, middle and bottom -- we can also see that together these are comprised of 10 elemental circuits. The top and bottom take 4 circuits together, and the middle averages 2 circuits.

So, from my novice calculations, each elemental circuit is about 48V total. Is this right?

Would you add anything to regulate source?

What happens to the current on the red diodes?

What happens to the voltage on the red diodes?

---

**Top and Bottom Circuit: 47.50V per series total**

- White LM301 EVO (62 x 2.8V)/4 series = 44.80V white
- Deep Red 660nm (6 x 1.8)/4 series = 2.70V deep red

**Middle Circuit: 47.50V per series total**

- White LM301 EVO (32 x 2.8V)/2 series = 44.80V white
- Deep Red 660nm and Far Red 730nm (3 x 1.8V)/2 series = 2.70V all-red

[image: SP1000 grow light]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> So, from my novice calculations, each elemental circuit is about 48V total. Is this right?

Your voltage calculations seem to be correct, except LED's [product page](https://led.samsung.com/lighting/mid-power-leds/3030-leds/lm301h/) suggests the white LEDs have a voltage of 2.7 V. But this is a very insignificant difference.

> Would you add anything to regulate source?

Usually these kinds of LED panels are used with an LED driver. The [product page](https://www.spider-farmer.com/products/sf-1000-led-grow-light/) of your panel suggests a specific [controller](https://www.spider-farmer.com/products/spider-farmer-led-grow-light-controller/). You can use your other LED drivers on your own risk if they match the current rating and voltage range.

> What happens to the current on the red diodes?

It seems from the circuit diagram that red LEDs carry twice the current as the white ones. This is not unusual, red LEDs need more current to emit the same amount of power because they have lower voltage.

> What happens to the voltage on the red diodes?

In a series connection, each element can independently have its own voltage, and we know the red LEDs have less voltage across them.

Comment: "red LEDs carry twice the current" That explains why the circuit is joined! Clever design to use LEDs with different current requirements. Guessing the red is Osram GH CSBRM4.24-V6V9-1-1 Square Hyper Red--2V 700mA LED.

Comment: I don't think it's good to get red led twice more current unless, they are rated for twice more current. If it's just to compensate from the lower voltage, then it's not good. But it's probably better than making separate series without any current balancing device for each series.

Comment: @Fredled the part numbers are already shared in the answer and the comments. White LEDs are rated for 300 mA and the red ones for 700 mA, per their datasheets.