# Is this LED circuit balanced?

Tags: led

I know that this first board is balanced and have posted about this here [2023 LED grow light voltage challenge?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/691670/2023-led-grow-light-voltage-challenge) The first board in question is squared up and all the series strings have approximately the same length trace. It looks like this (yellow-white LED, red-red LED, green-traces, red-power, gray-neg:[image]

Will the board currents and voltages remain balanced if the series strings are different lengths?

This picture gives an idea of what I'm referring to:
[image]

Am I overthinking this? Do trace run lengths even have an effect on the balance?

Comment: Resistance in the traces needs to be roughly comparable (or else small enough to be negligible) but length itself is irrelevant.

Comment: They do at very high frequencies, such as gigabit Ethernet, 10 gigabit Ethernet, PCI Express, etc.  At those frequencies, the depth of a plated-through hole is significant.

Comment: Even an order of magnitude difference in trace length is going to be dwarfed by the Vf variance of the LEDs.

Comment: What do you mean with balanced and why would it matter when powering LEDs with DC?

Comment: What are the yellow and red dots? [Edit] it into your question - not in the comments.

Answer (score 4):

> Will the board currents and voltages remain balanced if the series strings are different lengths?

The only thing that affects the distribution of current in an LED light is the sum of the LED forward voltages and the resistive losses (V=I*R) along the traces/resistors.  For things like grow lights, the current and resistance are both very low, so resistive losses are negligible.  This leaves only the sum of the LED forward voltages.

> Do trace run lengths even have an effect on the balance?

Unless the part is badly designed (very thin traces), no the length doesn't matter.  If you're concerned, look up the resistance per length of your traces and see how much difference it will make by multiplying the total resistance by your current.  This will give you the total voltage you will lose along the longer trace which you can compare to any other trace of interest.

Comment: Thank you again, user1850479 :)