# Resistor for LED grow light?

Tags: led, resistors, passive-components

Carrying on from related post ([2023 LED grow light voltage challenge?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/691670/2023-led-grow-light-voltage-challenge)), what resistors will best regulate the current in this circuit? Using 32x2.9v@200mA white and 3x1.9v@400mA red diodes. Link to schematic below.

I chose a 3.75 ohm resistors (notes below), based on a 50V supply running at 400mA. Is this correct?

But a 50V supply might not be enough, especially as this barely allows any overhead to meet the Vf of 49.25V. Any insight on voltage supply is appreciated.

Here are my calculation notes:
Vf = ((32x2.9v) + (3x1.9v)) / 2 = 49.25v.

Assuming Vs=50v, If=200mA, and Vf=49.25v,
then R = (50v - 49.25v) / .2A = 3.75 Ohm,
and W= (50v - 49.25v) x .2A = .150 W
[image: CircuitLab Schematic 9dta6t3ucv57]

Comment: You cannot assume that the LED forward voltages are absolutely accurate and have no tolerance specification. It might be that even if you connected a 0 ohm resistor the LEDs might not even draw 400mA with 50.0V supply. If you have data sheets for those LEDs you can look up the forward voltage range including initial tolerance and deviations due to temperature.

Comment: TBH I think you're making this harder than it needs to be by trying to use a 50V *constant voltage* supply. Commercial LED "light engines" (think street lights, etc) are almost exclusively driven by *constant current* supplies like [this one](https://www.amazon.com/Optotronic-Constant-120-277-1A4-DIM-1/dp/B08JVMDDH5/) for example.

Comment: Thank you, Justme and brhans!