Designing a DIY low level light therapy device (LLLT)
I am designing a low level light therapy (LLLT) device similar to the one in this video.


Mine will be smaller using twenty each (for a total of 40) of two kinds of 3W LEDs:

2.4V 0.6A -- 660Nm red
1.6V 0.4A -- 850Nm IR

I have two 5A DC-DC CC/CV buck converters to control voltage and current.
Buck converter specifications:

Input: 8V-36V
Output:
Voltage: 1.25V - 32V
Current: 5A maximum, adjustable

My plan is to have

4 rows of 5 red LEDs
4 rows of 5 IR LEDs.

The 5 LEDs in each row will be connected in series and the rows will be connected in parallel.
My question is about how I should set the voltage and current on the buck converters.  I think the voltage for the total red LEDs should be set at 12V and set at 8V for the IR LEDs.
I'm not sure what I should set the current at, as each set of 5 LEDs needs 0.6A for red but 2.4A in total (0.4A for IR 1.6A total.) Is that correct?
I have a desktop PC power supply that I am using for testing, and a PC fan for airflow.
I am planning on using high heat epoxy for attaching the LED starboards to an old piece of metal I have as a heat sink.

See this question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/691624/led-grow-light-series-regulation

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

120W of LEDs does not sound like "low level light". Those power levels are really unsuitable for your standard current limiting resistor. Share the datasheets for the LEDs and the DC/DC converters you have.

Thanks for your comment. I based my build on the tech specs of consumer light therapy products like the Joovv and others and research from the Huberman podcast.  I bought my components from Aliexpress. The specs of the DC to Dc Buck Converter are:  Input voltage: 8V-36V, Output voltage: 1.25V-32V, Output current: adjustable maximum 5A. The specs for the LEDs are above. Thanks.

Do you have a bench power supply, where you can control the current, so that you can test one Red LED? If so, set the current to 10mA and test a junk LED first, then your one Red LED. It should tell you the LED forward voltage. Slowly increase the current, and keep track of (current,Vf) in a table for eventual entry into a spreadsheet, to make yourself a V-I graph that you can share with us. You should also br able to enter the maximum voltage allowed. (But only allow for a moment). I usually make a temp heat sink and hold the LED+sink in my hand so I can gauge that aspect & not burn the LED.

Also, can we put the Red LED's in 5 colums of 4, making the nominal voltage 2.4V x 4 = 9.6V, which is closer to the 1.6V x 5 = 8V? It will still be "4 rows of 5 Red LEDs", just wired vertically instead of horizontally. Otherwise the Red LED strings will be 12V, and you can't use a 12V supply (there's no margin, for when temperature changes, or components age, etc).

on the tech specs of consumer light therapy products You may find out that the quality of engineering in those products leaves something to be desired… Perhaps a bad example to learn from.

@vir Low level in comparison to ablation systems. In an absolute sense it's a lot of wall plug power, but since the resulting light is spread out over a larger area the power density is low enough that you're not doing thermal damage.

With a load such as a LED, there is no separate current and voltage control. You either control voltage or current, never both at once.
So what you really needed are not 5V supplies, but so-called LED Drivers that regulate current. Voltage across an LED depends on temperature and past history of the part, so regulating it would be pointless and dangerous when all you want is generate some light and not do semiconductor research.
The current-regulating drivers have a specification called compliance voltage. That is the highest voltage they can generate while regulating the current. This voltage will determine how many LEDs you can connect in series. The drivers also have a range of voltages where they are most efficient, so even though most multi-LED drivers could drive just one LED, they’d waste quite a bit of power doing so.

Full disclosure up front -- I'm a serious hobbyist.
Test and confirm everything yourself, and get a real EE to do the proper engineering if you are going to even think about using this for anything but your own personal project. That said...

These circuits simulate the handling of the nominal case you've given.

2.4Vx4=9.6v 5x0.6A=3.0A -- 660Nm red.
1.6Vx5=8.0v 4x0.4A=1.6A -- 850Nm IR.

Here are two self-oscillating Buck converters simulated in LTspice for you. They are meant to be used per string, so every LED string is individually regulated. This is power-regulated, and not temperature-compensated at all, yet it may still meet your needs. The power source is a simple 12V in all cases.  Replacing R1 with a potentiometer, perhaps a 10-turn or 15-turn trimmer potentiometer, will allow you to set the power output to what you want. The regulation is power-in, so there is no chance of LED thermal runaway. You could replace the R1 resistors with digital potentiometers, and use a microcontroller to set the resistance of R1 and therefore the power output, using the microcontroller to equalize the output of all of the string (per type), and even perform a bit of temperature compensation (but the danger of thermal runaway may come back).
I have successfully made inexpensive coupled-inductors like these by the following method:  Buy an open-design unshielded power inductor that meets the specifications of the L1 power inductor, but with a lot of extra inductance (perhaps 150uH or 220uH), because you're going to unwind a bit of the wire (reducing the power inductance back down to 68uH). Using the extra space that you've gained, then you add a fairly thin winding to make the secondary. The secondary is a sense winding which can have a lot more resistance, which can offset the R1 resistor (which can be reduced to compensate), so the wire can be very thin. I use a cheap inductor measuring device from Amazon.
Or you can wind your own from scratch using a pot core from Digikey or similar.



Thanks @MicroservicesOnDDD

@BravoFoxtrot -- If you think my answer is worthy of thanks, perhaps you could hit the up-arrow, and upvote. That is one way of thanking us for putting in the work to give you a decent answer. If you don't upvote, that's okay too. (Then I haven't earned it, or the answer isn't really that useful. Again, okay.) Thanks for thanking me. If you have any questions, please don't hesitate to ask. May your project go very well. By the way, since my solution is more than 90% efficient, it should produce less heat than some other solutions, so your LED's might run cooler and therefore last longer.
